# Changing Class of Column Across Multiple Dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of 59 data frames that I want to merge together. Unfortunately, because I have scraped many of them, the columns in the data frames have different classes. They all have the column "Name", some in factor form and some in character form. I want to change all of them to character form. I tried the following

```
dts <- c("Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida",
               "Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine",
               "Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska",
               "Nevada","New_Hampshire","New_Jersey","New_Mexico","New_York","North_Carolina","North_Dakota",
               "Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode_Island","South_Carolina","South_Dakota","Tennessee",
               "Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West_Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming","Federal",
               "CCJail","DC","LAJail","NOLA","NYCJail","OCJail","PhilJail","TXJail")


for(i in 1:length(dts)){
        dts[i]$Name <- as.character(dts[i]$Name)
}
```

but it only gave me the error "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".
Does anyone know of a good work-around? Thanks in advance for the help!

My ultimate goal is to run

```
dta <-dplyr::bind_rows(Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Arkansas,California,Colorado,Connecticut,Delaware,Florida,
       Georgia,Hawaii,Idaho,Illinois,Indiana,Iowa,Kansas,Kentucky,Louisiana,Maine,
       Maryland,Massachusetts,Michigan,Minnesota,Mississippi,Missouri,Montana,Nebraska,
       Nevada,New_Hampshire,New_Jersey,New_Mexico,New_York,North_Carolina,North_Dakota,
       Ohio,Oklahoma,Oregon,Pennsylvania,Rhode_Island,South_Carolina,South_Dakota,Tennessee,
       Texas,Utah,Vermont,Virginia,Washington,West_Virginia,Wisconsin,Wyoming,Federal,CCJail,
       DC,LAJail,NOLA,NYCJail,OCJail,PhilJail,TXJail)
```

But I get the error "Error: Can't combine `..1$Residents.Confirmed`  and `..2$Residents.Confirmed` ." There are a ton of columns in each data frame, and they are different classes very often. if anyone has a more elegant solution, I would also be open to that instead! Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to change only the 'Name' column class or all the columns?

Comment: @arkun I ned to change all the columns (some to character, some to numeric). Thanks!

Comment: That is not clear.  Because it may also vary in each of the datasets.  I have added a solution to change all the character and then bind them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the datasets loaded into a `list` with `mget` (assuming the dataset objects are already created in the global environment) and then loop over the `list` with `map`, change the `class` of 'Name' column in `mutate` and row bind with suffix `_dfr` in `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map_dfr(mget(dts), ~ .x %>% 
                  mutate(Name = as.character(Name)))
```

---

If there are many columns that are different `class`.  May be, it is better to convert to a single class for all the columns and then bind

```
out <- map_dfr(mget(dts), ~ .x %>%
                   mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))
out <- type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)
```

If the `dplyr` version is `< 1.0.0`, use `mutate_all`

```
out <- map_dfr(mget(dts), ~ .x %>%
               mutate_all(as.character))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Right now, when I run code you suggested, it gives the following error: 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Can't recycle `..1` (size 507) to match `..20` (size 22).
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(everything(), as.character)`.

Comment: and when I run `rlang::last_error()` I get 
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Can't recycle `..1` (size 507) to match `..20` (size 22).
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(everything(), as.character)`.
Backtrace:
  1. purrr::map_dfr(...)
  2. purrr::map(.x, .f, ...)
  3. global::.f(.x[[i]], ...)
 12. dplyr::mutate(., across(everything(), as.character))
 14. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)

Comment: @babybonobo what is the version of `dplyr` I used 1.0.0

Comment: @babybonobo can you try with `mutate_all` as in the update

Comment: I'm using 1.0.0. Thanks for the help! I tried the `mutate_all` option but now it's giving me the error of 
Error: Invalid index: out of bounds

Comment: @babybonobo Not sure because it works `map_dfr(list(mtcars, mtcars), ~ .x %>% mutate_all(as.character))` with `dplyr 1.0.0`. Try on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` and `purrr` loaded

Comment: So... I had a bug that was making one of the "Name" columns (in California) a data frame within the California dataframe. Once I fixed that, your `mutate_all` command worked great! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 <- data.frame(
  Name = as.factor(c("name1", "name2")),
  Residents.Confirmed = c(0,1)
  )
d2 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("name3", "name4"),
  Residents.Confirmed = c(2,3)
)
dataframes_list <- list(d1, d2)
for(i in 1:length(dataframes_list)){
  dataframes_list[[i]]$Name <- as.character(dataframes_list[[i]]$Name)
}
bind_rows(dataframes_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
type.convert(do.call("rbind", 
        Map(function(x){data.frame(lapply(x, as.character))}, dataframes_list)))
```

Data thanks @chase171:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
  Name = as.factor(c("name1", "name2")),
  Residents.Confirmed = c(0,1)
)
d2 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("name3", "name4"),
  Residents.Confirmed = c(2,3)
)
dataframes_list <- list(d1, d2)
```